# Allow a user to login/signin between actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a requirement, where we allow a user to access a URL without logging in until a certain point.
For example:

OnlineBooking/Services.  They can select the services, this populates the viewmodel and then brings up a confirm view OnlineBooking/Confirm allowing a user to add an email address etc.  Which then generates a ViewModel.

My question is, how can I check the user exists, if it does.  Redirect to the login view (Account Controller - Login Action), allow them to login, then redirect back to this action without losing the viewmodel in this action?  This may not even be possible, if not how can I achieve this?
Thanks for any advice.

Example:

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Confirm(BookingViewModel bookingViewModel)
    {
        try
        {  
            var matchedUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(bookingViewModel.Email);
            if (matchedUser == null) //User does not have an existing account, so register them.
            {
              //This is fine
            }
            else
            {
              //Need to redirect to login, then back to here without losing the viewmodel
            }
     }
```

Comment: [AllowAnonymous](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-allowanonymous-attribute-and-authorize-attribute) attribute was designed for that very purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how can I check the user exists, if it does. Redirect to the login view (Account Controller - Login Action), allow them to login, then redirect back to this action without losing the viewmodel in this action

My personal preference would be to not even redirect the user.  If you need them to login, popup a dialog asking them to login.  Once the user is logged in (ajax), enable the button to continue..

Comment: This sounds more user friendly. Do you have an example I can look at please?

Comment: I'm not affiliated in any way, but if you check out http://www.southwest.com and search for a flight, on the right is a login, you can login litterally anytime in the process.  Many many many websites do this.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I agree it is a better process. Do you know of any examples that I can use to implement this, with also retaining the viewmodel in this action.

Comment: If you use ajax, you don't need to refresh the page, thus you keep your viewmodel intact.

Comment: This worked perfectly in a partial view containing the login with an ajax post hooking into the success event and enabling the button without causing a page refresh and therefore retaining the viewmodel.

Comment: @DavidBeaumont Nice job man!  I'd bet that was pretty awesome feeling once it was working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best practice, but what about storing the View Model in the session before you redirect to the login page?  Then at the beginning of the confirm action, check if that session variable exists.

Session variables can be set like this:

```
Session["MyViewModel"] = viewModel;
```

and retrieved like so:

```
MyViewModel viewModel = (MyViewModel)Session["MyViewModel"]
```

Comment: This is one way to do it as long as your object is serializable.